# xubuntu: color problem after upgrading to 14.10

Tags: upgrade, xfce

I just upgraded from 14.04 to 14.10. The process went smoothly, no event. But afterwards, no matter which theme I choose, dark colors (black, etc) becomes shades of purple, as if some kind of palette problem.

Any one come across this before and have a cure?

Comment: @DKBose Yeah. That's exactly what I see. So it's a bug? Kinda put me off xubunut, which is a shame. Also I don't know what else I could try. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out it isn't a bug but just something to highlight how customizable Xubuntu is!

> Highlights and known issues
>
> To celebrate the 14.10 codename “Utopic Unicorn” and to demonstrate the easy customisability of Xubuntu, highlight colors have been turned pink for this release. You can easily revert this change by using the theme configuration application (gtk-theme-config) under the Settings Manager; simply turn Custom Highlight Colors “Off” and click “Apply”. Of course, if you wish, you can change the highlight color to something you like better than the default blue!

[Source](http://xubuntu.org/news/xubuntu-14-10-beta-2-is-released/)

Comment: Nice one. But the QT application looking ugly problem is still there.